# How to use 2 OnClick events on a HTML 5 Button

Tags: html

the separate OnClick events are:

```
window.location.href='http://www.google.com.au';  
return ewt.trackLink({name:'test',type:'customname',link:this});
```

would using them together look like:

```
<button type="button" onClick="window.location.href='.google.com.au';return ewt.trackLink({name:'test',type:'customname',link:this});">Button</button>
```

any help much appreciated.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: You have a proposed solution, and you haven't tried it yet?

Comment: I have, but im not sure if its not working because of the javascript syntax or because of another tagging issue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what, exactly, isn't working, but my guess is that the second statement isn't being executed. If this is the case, it's happening because you're redirecting the user by changing `window.location.href`, which prevents any additional JS from running.

Reversing the order of your handlers *should* resolve this problem:

```
<button type="button" onClick="ewt.trackLink({name:'test',type:'customname',link:this}); window.location.href='.google.com.au';">Button</button>
```

You should also consider using [`.addEventLister`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which is a flexible, unobtrusive solution for attaching multiple event handlers to a single element.

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('do this');
    //ewt.trackLink({name:'test',type:'customname',link:this});
});

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('now do this');
    //window.location.href='.google.com.au';
});
```